# Programming e-ink display on atmega32 without arduino

Tags: c, avr, spi

i've bought eink 1,54 display module from waveshare, i want to program atmega32 and design a gui with keys on this eink. I wrote a simple code using spi in eclipse:

```
  #include <avr/io.h>
  #include <util/delay.h>

  void Inicjacja_spi()
  {
      DDRB = ( 1 << PB5 ) | ( 1 << PB7 ) | ( 1 << PB4 );                                      

      SPCR = ( 1 << SPE ) | ( 1 << MSTR ) | (1<<SPI2X) |( 1 << SPR1 ) | ( 1 << SPR0 );   
  }                            


  void Wyslij_spi(unsigned char bajt)
  {
      SPDR = bajt;                        

      while( ! bit_is_set( SPSR, SPIF ) );
  }


  int main()
  {
      unsigned char bajt[] = {0x04,0x20,0x21,0x22,0x25,0x26,0x27};

      Inicjacja_spi();

      for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
          Wyslij_spi(bajt[i]);

       while(1)
       {
       }
   }
```

I have read about how to send commands through spi to this eink but it didnt work. Do i have to write complicated libraries to send some data into display? I guess it should work using simple commands, but maybe i'am doing somethin wrong. If someone can tell me how can i write simple commands into this thing because i dont understand those documentations. Simple working example should help me.

Comment: 1. You can look into the sources of the Arduino libraries to see how they do it. You need to understand what's in there, and then strip off all stuff you don't need.

Comment: 2. You take your oscilloscope and record the signals. There are quite affordable devices, and if you lower the SPI clock they can show decend results. Then look at the traces and compare them to the expected signals.

Comment: 3. To find working examples for SPI on ATmega32 you can use your beloved search engine for the web. There should be lots of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the display manufacturers documentation first.

Typically these devices need specific drivers and the manufacturer supplies these along with some example code.

The displays themselves normally require some driver hardware, is this included in or with your display module?

I'm sorry but as you don't give any information regarding the display other than where you bought it from and its size I can't be more specific.

**edit**
Just had a very quick scan through and see that there's a link to a library written to drive these using SPI  - [Library source on GIT hub](https://github.com/ZinggJM/GxEPD)
You may be able to adapt it, or glean something useful from the source code.

Comment: Yes, i have TXB0108 voltage level translator connected into my display and uC. This is schematic: 
 https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/5b/1.54inch_e-Paper_Schematic.pdf 
On Vccb i connected 5v from uC, on VccA i connected 3,3V from dc/dc. X'(pins 1-10) are connected into PFC24, X(pins 11-20) are connected into uC SPI.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm a bit busy today, but I'll have  look at it when I get the chance. I'm assuming that its a version 2 display.